# VLC DotNet capture frame

Tags: c#, video-capture, vlc, snapshot, libvlc

I use [Vlc.DotNet 2.1](https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet) packages to connect to my webcam and every thing is OK, But my problem is I need to capture(Grab) each frame as an image to be able to process these images. **libvlc.dll** has ***libvlc_video_take_snapshot***  method that takes snapshot and saves that to a *.PNG* file. I used this method and now I'm able to take snapshots to file, read them from file then process each one. This solution's problem is its lag. Because of that I have to take snapshots in memory, process images then dispose them.
How can I do this?

Comment: You could try use vmem module (libvlc_video_set_format_callbacks, libvlc_video_set_callbacks) - but don't know if it accessable via Vlc.DotNet

Comment: These methods don't exist in Vlc.DotNet. I think I should implement them my self and call from libvlc.dll

Comment: Keep in mind, if you will use vmem - you will have to draw frames yourself on window - it disables standard output.